# I would like a statement that will count the project_name

Tags: sql

I would like a statement that will count the project_name of how many students went 'India Ahmednagar' i will need to use a 'COUNT' condition  but every time i use it i get errors (ACT_ID, ACT_DEC, DESC) (PROJECT_NAME) I will need a volunteer_id added in to count the students in 'India Ahmednagar'

```
SELECT 
     ACTIVITY_ID,
     ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION,
     DESCRIPTION,
     PROJECT_NAME AS PROJECT
FROM
     TASK_ACTIVITY
INNER JOIN
     VOLUNTEER ON VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEER_ID = TASK_ACTIVITY.VOLUNTEER_ID
INNER JOIN
     TASK ON TASK.TASK_ID = TASK_ACTIVITY.TASK_ID
INNER JOIN
     PROJECT ON PROJECT.PROJECT_ID = TASK.PROJECT_ID
ORDER BY NAME;
```

Comment: Hint: `count case when someColumn = 'someCondition' then 1 end` or simply `select project_name, count(*) from Project group by project_name`

Comment: Don't spam all the database tags.  Update and drop unnecessary tags.

Comment: sorry pal just need help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a student's location is determined by this field:

```
VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEER_ID
```

You could have a query as follows:

```
SELECT      
     VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEER_ID
   , COUNT(VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEER_ID)     
FROM
     VOLUNTEER    
GROUP BY VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEER_ID
HAVING VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEER_ID = 'India Ahmednagar ID'
```

If you want to add any other fields to the SELECT list, be sure to include them in the GROUP BY clause. I removed your joins just for the sake of simplicity.